# Issue making Bootstrap3 icon spin

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Inspired by [Fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/examples/#animated-spinner), I'm trying to make a spinning icon with bootstrap3. It's easily achieve via CSS3 transition and transform. Problem is the icon does not not rotate around the center. It swings while rotating.

Code pasted below. Anyone know what causes the problem?

```css
.spin {
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <h1 class="text-center">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh spin"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record spin"></span>
    </h1>
```

Comment: it's working for me but in my application when click loading is started

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The issue is that you rotate an element which is not centered in your span.

If you want a real solution, add `transform-origin` on `.spin` to change the center of rotation

```
.spin{
     -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 58%;
     transform-origin:50% 58%;
     -ms-transform-origin:50% 58%; /* IE 9 */
     -webkit-animation: spin .2s infinite linear;
     -moz-animation: spin .2s infinite linear;
     -o-animation: spin .2s infinite linear;
     animation: spin .2s infinite linear;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L4zTu/5/

Comment: Its a fix only for `<h1>` case, if you try spin a icon with other font-size parent, will flick. http://jsfiddle.net/L4zTu/3/

Comment: You're right. I have found the solution. The problem is the origin of the rotation. Check the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L4zTu/5/

Comment: Thanks Donovan and Oswaldo. Further question is why the y-axis is 58%?

Comment: This is definitely the solution to the problem, but the y-axis percentage varies by font-size. So one class will not work for all elements, as stated by Oswaldo, and readers will just need to play with the number until it looks right. It will be within +/-10 of 50%.

Answer (score 61):

I wrote a [blog](http://chadkuehn.com/animated-font-spinners/) post about this. Simply reference the glyphicon with a custom class:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-spin"></span>
```

The `glyphicon-spin` class was constructed by studying the `fa-spin` class in the FontAwesome stylesheet:

```css
h4 {
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.fa-spin-custom, .glyphicon-spin {
    -webkit-animation: spin 1000ms infinite linear;
    animation: spin 1000ms infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
        transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
        transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h4>FontAwesome</h4>

<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>

<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>

<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>

<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin-custom"></i>

<br />
<br />

<h4>Glyphicons</h4>
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-spin"></span>
```

Comment: Works just as intended. Would be a shame to include FontAwesome solely for a single spinning icon.

Comment: Still relevant for a legacy app I had to work on. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

An additional point, if following this example.

The keyframe definitions need to allow for the case where some properties will be un-vendor prefixed and others won't. For example, in Chrome 35 the current keyframe definitions won't work as keyframes isn't vendor prefixed, but transform still is.

Something like this should allow for all current/future cases:

```
@-moz-keyframes spin
{
    from
    {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to
    {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin
{
    from
    {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to
    {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes spin
{
    from
    {
        -wekbit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to
    {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Font Awesome has a nice convenient way of getting an icon to spin:

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/

Comment: Only that the OP is not using FontAwesome (except for inspiration) but the glyphicons from BS3

Comment: It works with bootstrap 3 glyphicons also. oops I misread (or didnt read) the OP's entire post. sorry

Answer (score 2):

Non of the above worked for me but this:

```
.spin {
        animation: spin infinite 4s linear;
        height: 80px;
    }

    @keyframes spin {
        from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
        to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might help someone using font-awesome.

Just try this.

```
<span class="sync-state pull-right" style="display: none;">
    <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i> synching..
</span>
```

Then on your javascript just get the element by class onclick or on hover which ever works best for you.

```
$(".sync-state").fadeIn();
```

After event action you can

```
$(".sync-state").fadeOut();
```

Hope this help. 
Jquery & Font-awesome

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap provides you a defined class library to do that.
Use "icon-spin" class along with your icon class 
For example:- `<i class="icon-refresh icon-spin"></i`>

Comment: This is not for Bootstrap3

Comment: Nor any other version of Bootstrap. Where did you get the idea that this would work?