# how to blink button with angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css

I am developing angularJs SPA application. My front end html page has a button upon clicking it waits for the operation to be completed. I would like user to notify that operation is in progress. Until the operation completes I am thinking of blinking the button or text on the button or any other approach that people might be using for the given scenario. 
I am open for suggestions like spinners on the button or anything that conveys user the correct state.

Comment: Does this button processing for only once or can process repeatedly by click one after another without refresh page? 1. execute once, I think it makes sense to replace the button with some loading label to indicate it's one time submit. 2. execute multi times, you can disable the button during the progress and have some loading icon and enable the button once it's done the processing.

Comment: As of now, it is one click or single submit event. I am ok with option1 as well as with option 2. 1) button is enabled on form load, 2) user clicks button to start the operation 3) need to convey user from web page operation is in progress 4) operation completed, the button is disabled. How do I achieve the above with angularJs?

Comment: $scope.formState = 1/2/3/4 as you described, ng-disabled="formState>1", ng-show="formState >1 &&formState" //show loading

Comment: Can't that be done purely in CSS?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by a Boolean variable.

For eg:

```
$scope.inProgress = false;
$scope.someAction = someAction;

function someAction(){
   $scope.inProgress = true;

   //action here
   //on result
   $scope.inProgress = false;
}
```

After operation is completed set the variable to false.

in html

```
    <button>
      <span ng-if="!inProgress">
        Submit
      </span>
      <span ng-if="inProgress">
        In progress
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-spin"></i>
      </span> 
    </button>
```

Adding some styles

```
button{
  padding:5px;
}
button span{
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.glyphicon-spin {
    -webkit-animation: spin 1000ms infinite linear;
    animation: spin 1000ms infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
        transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
        transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
```

It will create a spinning effect inside the button. You can customize it yourself.

Comment: I also found the following question useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364726/issue-making-bootstrap3-icon-spin